# How to add bool type to table?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm writing method in my model for saving values to database and have some trouble with bool type **"cannot implicitly convert type bool to string"**.
How should look correct method to save string and bool values to my Database table?

The Table Model:

```
  public class Table
  {
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public bool Yes { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

The Save Method:

```
public void SaveToDb()
{
 var db2 = new DatabaseEntities();
 db2.Table.Add(new Table(){ Name=Name, Yes=Yes} //get error here with "Yes"
 db2.SaveChanges();
}
```

SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
[Id]       INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]     NVARCHAR (50)   NULL
[Yes]      BIT             NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Is `Table.Yes` a `bool`? The message says you're trying to assign a `bool` to a `string`, so I'm guessing `Table.Yes` here is a `string`instead of `bool`

Comment: It should be `Yes = true`

Comment: i dont have c# table class, im getting values from my FormView, pass to my controller and save to database with this model method

Comment: What happens when you use `new Table(){ Name="name", Yes=true}` (that is, with explicit values)? Also: when do you get the error, when compiling or when running?

Comment: You are using `new Table()`, so that *is* a class in your code (may be auto-generated). Set the cursor on that "Table" and hit F12 to go to the definition. What is the type of the Yes property there?

Comment: Can you show your configuration for entity please?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing i get error when compiling. i checked Table class as you say and there "Yes" is string 'public string Yes { get; set; }'

Comment: Did you try `db2.Table.Add(new Table(){ Name=Name, Yes=true});`?

Comment: @mjwills `Yes=true` reutrns "cannot implicitly convert type bool to string"

Comment: @mjwills in my model class i have `public bool Yes { get; set; }` but in my auto-generated Table class is `public string Yes { get; set; }`. someone eddited my question

Comment: Why do you have two different Table classes?

Comment: it autogenerate itself when i start typing `db2.Table.Add(new Table(){ Name=Name, Yes=true});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit method like this.

```
public void SaveToDb()
{
 bool yes =true; //You can add true or false according to your needs
 var db2 = new DatabaseEntities();
 db2.Table.Add(new Table(){ Name=Name, Yes=yes } 
 db2.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: There is literally no way that can work - since the OP said `db2.Table.Add(new Table(){ Name=Name, Yes=true });` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, there doesn’t seem to be a comma in sql create table between name and yes columns. I assume that the table is already in place so this may not be significant.